# How to get Bullet Points to show in HTML Tabs

Tags: html, css

very new to web design and I'm trying to fool around and create a little website about myself. I've succeeded in creating tabs for different subjects, but when I try to create an unordered list within a tab, I see only the text displayed side by side and not bullets.

The HTML Code for an example tab is as follows:

```
<div id = "About Me" class = "tabcontent">
            <h3>About Me</h3>
            <p>This section of my website will talk about me. Things to talk about:</p>
                <ul class="a">
                    <l>My upbringing</l>
                    <l>The places I've lived</l>
                    <l>My interests and hobbies</l>
                </ul>
        </div>
```

The style for ul class a is as follows:

```
ul.a
{
    list-style-type: square;
}
```

The output I get for this is as follows:

About Me

This section of my website will talk about me. Things to talk about:
My upbringing The places I've lived My interests and hobbies

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: List item tags are `<li></li>`; you seem to have forgotten the `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list items are just using a misspelled list item tag.

Use `<li>` instead of `<l>`

Comment: Happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 2):

the tag for list items of ordered and unordered lists is misspelled:

```
<div id = "About Me" class = "tabcontent">
        <h3>About Me</h3>
        <p>This section of my website will talk about me. Things to talk about:</p>
            <ul class="a">
                <li>My upbringing</li>
                <li>The places I've lived</li>
                <li>My interests and hobbies</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

Should do the trick :-)